# WCF newbie with a WCF service that doesn't want to work (metadata I think)

Tags: wcf

I'm pretty new to this WCF game and I have some problems. I shall start at the beginning.

I set up a WCF service from an example I saw online. After I set it up, I used the Vis Studio service test thing and all was good. Image is here:

[image]

After that, I followed the instructions and put it as a reference inside a WCF web site project, which is a default project type in Vis Studio 2010. As directed to in the tutorial, I changed the 'Service' attribute in the svc file to [project in dll name].[class name for service].

When I went to 'edit WCF configuration' in this project, it didn't give me any services as it had done in the tutorial, so I figured I'd piece it together myself. I opened up the web.config file and wrote in the following:

[image]

Now I went on to add this as an application to IIS. If I browse the service in the published folder, it takes me to localhost/[SiteName]/[ServiceName].svc. It tells me the name of the service, and that I have created a service all that. I assume this means it is working correctly so far.

The problem comes when I try to add a service reference in a Silverlight project. It asks me for the address of the service, so I give it the svc address on the local host. It says, "There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address". Now I copied the svc path out of the address bar when I browsed the service from IIS, so I assume that's right.

Question is, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great, well written question! Now... you're running the service in IIS, correct (not running in visual studio development server)? You can browse and see the blue & white page 'You have created a service. Test to test this service, ...' etc. Is there a link ending in `wsdl` that you can click to view an xml document?

Comment: First time someone's complimented me, but I do make an effort to write clear questions. The times people take the time to read them, I get some pretty useful results. So thanks for reading it.

On to the issue - Yes, IIS 6.1 on Win 7. Yes, at the top there is the wsdl link and I can click on it. It does take me to some kind of XML document. I close most of the nodes so it would fit inside a screen cap, which can be seen here:

[Or, more accurately, here.](http://i.imgur.com/4MkRK.jpg)

Comment: I can only suggest adding the wsdl link to the silverlight app as the service reference (rather than the svc link). The wsdl file **is** the metadata, which somewhat contradicts your error message. I don't know of any reason that a regular WCF service wouldn't be able to be added as a service reference.

Comment: I did get the more detailed error that SL provided. This is **an image** from when I provided it with the /Eval.svc?wsdl link...   

[This is the link to the image](http://i.imgur.com/3Pm1Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

Have you tried
localhost/[SiteName]/[ServiceName]
or
localhost/[SiteName]/[ServiceName]?wsdl
or
localhost/[SiteName]/[ServiceName]/mex
?

I don´t use WCF with IIS, but i would think one these should work.

Comment: You mean when adding the service reference to Silverlight?

Comment: Yes, but your image in the last comment shows that you do enter the correct link. It seems the IIS sends the xml in content-type application/soap+xml, vs expects text/xml. Maybe you can change the content-type within your IIS somewhere?

Comment: I, err, don't really know how to do that. I have had a question up on StackOverflow for three days on it, but no answers.

Comment: You could try to make an executable, hosting the service. Can´t help with IIS, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following code below the endpoint element in your service.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
```

The above endpoint is needed for metadata exchange.